# "pip install" AWS Glue Python Shell Job - change package index?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, artifactory, aws-glue

Is it possible to change the package index of the `pip install` running in an AWS Glue Python Shell Job for when it tries to install additional dependencies?

I have `awswrangler` in the job dependencies, which is already provided as a `wheel`. Unfortunately that's not enough to get the job running as the installation of the wheel (obviously through pip) tries to install other dependencies (botocore, pg8000...) and fails because, due to security settings, pip cannot reach PyPI. We have an Artifactory which would be reachable by the job and which has mirrors of all dependencies. All I needed to do would be to tell the Glue Job pip to use that as index instead of PyPI.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not familiar with glue, but if it lets you set env variables you can set `PIP_FIND_LINKS`.

Comment: Is the "--additional-python-modules" job argument not working due to your security constraints? If so, you could consider uploading the modules to S3 and referencing them using "--extra-py-files" job argument.

Comment: have you tried https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/2.4.0-docs/install.html#aws-glue-python-shell-jobs ?

Comment: @jonlegend The job argument is afaik only available in Glue 2.0. Python Shell Jobs do not support Glue 2.0 (yet). As far as I know...

Comment: @HendrikWiese it appears that the "--extra-py-files" is supported, but you are right about "--additional-python-modules" not being supported for python shell jobs.  Take a look at this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html, and see the section titled *Providing Your Own Python Library*. It appears that both egg or whl is supported.

Comment: @jonlegend That's the way if your Glue Job has internet access. Unfortunately, ours runs in a secured VPC that does not have access to PyPI. So we cannot install any dependencies from anywhere else but our VPC. In my experience, packing a Wheel with dependencies does not actually pack the dependencies themselves but results in a basically empty wheel that still makes pip try to install the Wheels from PyPI. We would need to package everything (the whole dependency tree) into a single Wheel and provide that to the Glue Job in a way that pip only and solely installs that Wheel and nothing else.

Comment: Some combination of --find-links and --only-binary=:all: may help. Sorry, I haven't had to deal with this situation. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-only-binary https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-find-links

Comment: @jonlegend No need to apologize. I appreciate your help! In fact we do have access to PyPI (respectively our Artifactory mirror) from the CI pipeline that builds the job. So we *could* create a wheel that incorporates everything. It just has to have everything on board when it is going to be installed by the Glue Job's `pip` as that's the stage where no internet access is possible. So we'll see if we can bundle everything into one big wheel before it gets deployed to the corresponding library S3 bucket. Again, thanks for your help. Any further advice would still be greatly appreciated!